# React-Native: propTypes and createClass deprecated

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, deprecated

I'm beginning in React Native. I followed the instruction as recommended:

react-native init myProject. So to test the running application, I used the remote JS debugging to check if everything is ok.

Then I saw that propTypes and createClass are deprecated.

I don't know how to migrate this to the new version. (The instructions are for React and not React Native, I didn't use createClass but extends Component for example)

[image]

Here are my dependencies :
    "react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
    "react-native": "0.45.1",

Here is my code :

```
'use strict';

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';

export default class myProject extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <View >
        <Text >
          Welcome to React Native!
        </Text>
        <Text >
          To get started, edit index.android.js
        </Text>
        <Text >
          Double tap R on your keyboard to reload,{'\n'}
          Shake or press menu button for dev menu
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('myProject', () => myProject);
```

Answer (score 1):

For prop types you should now use the prop-types package:
https://github.com/facebook/prop-types

For createClass you should now use the create-react-class package:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-react-class

Read more about it [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2017/04/07/react-v15.5.0.html).

Comment: "I don't know how to migrate this to the new version. (The instructions are for React and not React Native, I didn't use createClass but extends Component for example)"

Comment: It's the same for react-native. react-native is basically react with different components. Same syntax though..

Comment: Well, but why createClass? I didn't used it, I used extends Components for react-native and in the basic code of react-native project, props are not used yet

Comment: If you used extends Component so you should be good.. You get a yellow box deprecation message? Maybe something in your template uses createClass?

Comment: It's just the basic from react-native init.. I put my code to the post

Comment: Tried ton import prop-types as the instructions but still the warning.

Comment: That's really unexpected.. Mind adding the exact log you see at the remote JS debugging? Is it a warn type log?

Comment: added in the post, it's speaks about i'm accessing propType. But the init project is like that, I didn't modified anything. How can I update this? I can't update all one by one in each libs, it's will be just horrible

Comment: Ok, I saw a lot of people downgrade the version of React Native because of this...